# Dynamic function names in R

Tags: r

What I need to do is use both the `which.min` and `which.max` functions in R in a loop.

I could just use an `if` statement (ie `if find_max_value == TRUE then which.max(…) else which.min(…)`

but I was wondering if there is a way to actually make the function name dynamic.
For example:

```
min_or_max =  'max'
special_text = paste('which.',min_or_max,sep='')
special_text(df_results$point)
```

is there somehow to make the above text work?

Comment: You can paste together function or object names, but it tends to make things **very** fragile and hard to debug. It's often better to pass functions directly as arguments, or use control/flow code (if statements and the like) to handle cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to choose from a list of possible functions, better to store them in a list. For example

```
funs <- list(max = which.max, min=which.min)
min_or_max =  'max'
funs[[min_or_max]](df_results$point)
```

This is much safer than trying to use arbitrary strings as code. Plus you can validate that a proper value exists before you try to run the code: `min_or_max  %in% names(funs)`

Comment: why the double brackets?

Comment: The double brackets will return the function from the list. Using single brackets will subset the list (returning a list).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `do.call` is what you are looking for:

```r
min_or_max =  'max'
special_text = paste('which.',min_or_max,sep='')
do.call(special_text, list(mtcars$cyl))
#> [1] 5
```

Comment: yep, exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `invoke` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
invoke(special_text, list(mtcars$cyl))
#[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `match.fun` :

```
match.fun(special_text)(mtcars$mpg)
#[1] 20

#Verifying the results
which.max(mtcars$mpg)
#[1] 20
```